# how to use the turtle.reset() function without a function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I don't know how to show the code in short terms, but I can give it a try. I am wondering how to get the turtle.reset() to work when the turtle was created in a function:

```
def scissors(x,y):
  scissors = turtle.Turtle()

  scissors.speed(0)
  scissors.color("maroon")
  scissors.fillcolor("red")
```

It goes on with code for rock paper and scissors
then:

```
while choice == "yes" or choice == "Yes":
   if:
     (some other stuff)
   elif:
```

so on and so on, but at the end I would like to reset and I do:

```
  rock.reset()
  paper.reset()
  scissors.reset()
```

and after going through everything in the if else statements, when it reaches the reset function it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'reset' on line 318
```

Please help me(if needed link to project below)

https://repl.it/@WeirdDragon/RPS#main.py

Comment: My guess is this is due to your having a function named `scissors()` and a variable named `scissors`.  Change the name of one of them.

Comment: @cdlane is correct - you need to change either the turtle name or the function name.

Comment: All relevant code should be in the question itself as a [mcve].